# Type mismatch: why there is .Companion?

Tags: kotlin, generics, companion-object

I wrote the following function:

```
fun <T> myFunction(res: Response, type: T): T {
        return res.`as`(type!!::class.java)
}
```

And I would like to use it in the following way:

```
fun anotherFunction(): MyClass {
        val res = getResponse()
        return myFunction(res, MyClass)
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Type mismatch.
>
> Required: MyClass
>
> Found: MyClass.Companion

How can I solve it?

Comment: what is `as` function? How is `MyClass` defined?

Comment: @sidgate The `as` function is from REST Assured. And the `MyClass` implementation should not matter for the purpose of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the `as` function does, but I suppose it performs some sort of conversion from one class instance into an instance of some other class?

You seem to be trying to pass a class type as a function argument. You can do it in one of two ways:

```
fun <T: Any> myFunction(res: Response, type: Class<T>): T {
    return res.`as`(type)
}

fun anotherFunction(): MyClass {
    val res = getResponse()
    return myFunction(res, MyClass::class.java)
}
```

or

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> myFunction(res: Response): T {
    return res.`as`(T::class.java)
}

fun anotherFunction(): MyClass {
    val res = getResponse()
    return myFunction(res) // <MyClass> is inferred by anotherFunction return type
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About the first method, it is not what I want, because in `anotherFunction` I don't want to write `::class.java`. The second method is absolutely great, even better than I thought at the beginning, because it automatically takes the return type.